# How to use R list using variable name to assign

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a JSON file using Lists in R. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
toJSON(list(j$key=projIssues)) #I get error that I can't do this    

print(j$key)#---displays ACME
```

Here's how I created the above in a static manner, but would like to do it dynamically.

```
projIssues = list(
    issueName = i$name,
    total=y$total
    )

toJSON(list(key=projIssues))
```

The above returns:

```
{
   "ACME": {
            "issueName": "Wish",
            "total":      6 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question. If what you want is to change the key, you can use the `names` function.

```
J = list(list(a=1,b=2))
names(J) = "ACME"
cat(toJSON(J))
```

Comment: Thanks Randy for the solution